# Failed to start dphys-swapfile.service

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os

I just got my raspberry pi 4 and I set up my pi by berryboot. Then I did `sudo apt-get install sysbench`on my pi which game me `E: Unable to locate package sysbench`. I looked up line and tried`sudo apt-get upgrade -y` and `sudo apt-get update`. For the upgrade, it returns the following error to me.

```
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dphys-swapfile.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-12-16 20:41:38 GMT; 21ms ago
     Docs: man:dphys-swapfile(8)
  Process: 14735 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14758 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile swapon (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
 Main PID: 14758 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
Dec 16 20:41:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file...
Dec 16 20:41:38 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[14735]: want /var/swap=2048MByte, checking existing: keeping it
Dec 16 20:41:38 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[14758]: swapon: /var/swap: swapon failed: Invalid argument
Dec 16 20:41:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Dec 16 20:41:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 16 20:41:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.5Gi       624Mi       4.2Gi       175Mi       2.8Gi       6.6Gi
```

Basically, the system failed to start  dphys-swapfile which is responsible for set-up, install, delete files.(I believe). If you had this problem before, please help me out. I have tried different methods and reinstall my pi for a few times.

At the end, Merry Christmas.

Comment: The end of your `apt-get` log looks like the output of `free` for some reason.

Comment: I was having this issue but it seemed to resolve itself after rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

There are some things mixed up in your question. The update/upgrade sequence is wrong. You must first update and then do better a full upgrade instead of only an upgrade:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

> For the upgrade, it returns the following error to me

and you show us an output from `systemctl status dphys-swapfile.service`. This cannot be. The upgrade is an **apt/apt-get** command and does not output a systemctl status. Then I cannot see what the installation of **sysbench** has to do with the swap file. I think there is no relation to it. It seems to be only a coincidence or a side effect.

This all is very confusing and does not explain what you have really done with your installation. I suggest to start with a fresh flashed Raspberry Pi OS. The swapfile service will run then out of the box without errors.

Then do an update/full-upgrade as shown above in that sequence and reboot. Look if **sysbench** is available:

```
rpi ~$ apt list sysbench
Listing... Done
sysbench/stable 0.4.12-1.2+b1 armhf
```

and install it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install sysbench
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case this happened after I resized the disk using raspi-config after recovering a backed up image. Looking at the logs with `sudo journalctl -xe` I noticed the following error message:

```
swapon: /var/swap: skipping - it appears to have holes.
```

So in the assumption that the swap file would just be recreated when needed by the same script, I removed it with `sudo rm /var/swap` and restarted the swapfile service with `sudo systemctl start dphys-swapfile.service` which did fix the problem as per the logs:

```
want /var/swap=100MByte, generating swapfile of 100MBytes
```

By the way, your assumptions about the swap(files) are incorrect: the swap space is used for memory management in linux. Very roughly speaking it is used when you are running low on memory then the (linux) kernel will swap memory used by processes in and out of the swap space when needed.

The swap file just uses a file on disk, rather than the more traditional setup where the swap space is a dedicated partition on disk.

Comment: Create a new swap file `cd /var;rm swap;dd if=/dev/zero of=swap count=2048 bs=1MiB;chmod 0600 swap;mkswap swap;dphys-swapfile swapon`

Comment: I think manually creating a swapfile isn't the best way to go here, because the automatically generated swapfile will respect the configuration in /etc/dphys-swapfile.

Comment: This worked approach resolved my issue with `dphys-swapfile`. In my case I upgraded kernel from `stretch 4.19.66-v7+` to `buster 5.10.52-v7+` using `apt full-upgrade`, yet this error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turns out it was using stat to determine the filesystem and it was broken (causing segfaults). Did a `apt-get reinstall coreutils` and a start of dphys-swapfile and it started working again